# javaScript in <head> section of WP API

Tags: php, functions, widgets, javascript

How do I place the following javaScript in the `<head>` section of the Wordpress *Widgets* API menu screen?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(window).load(function() {
        jQuery("#logocheckbox").change(function() {
            jQuery("#logocheckboxdiv").fadeToggle("slow");
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: I didn't dig through your PHP code, as this sounds like it's a jQuery related issue. The jsFiddle works, and assuming you're using the same approach, are you sure that the jQuery Selector is correct in the WP Admin Widgets screen? Perhaps your selector doesn't match any elements and therefore the contents do not appear when checkbox is ticked.  
**EDIT** Scrap that, I just noticed your jQuery code at the bottom of that `functions.php` codeblock. The selector seems to be fine.

Comment: Using WordPress Debugging, I'm getting the following Notices -- Notice: Undefined index: checkbox in /wp-content/themes/twentyeleven/functions.php on line 299

Notice: Undefined index: select in /wp-content/themes/twentyeleven/functions.php on line 300

More importantly, my browser is outputting an Uncaught TypeError, but I will post that as my answer.

Comment: Multi-post: http://stackoverflow.com/q/15637431 See: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function load_custom_logo_js($hook) {   
     if( 'widgets.php' != $hook )
         return;

     echo ('
     <script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(window).load(function() {
            jQuery("#logocheckbox").change(function() {
                jQuery("#logocheckboxdiv").fadeToggle("slow");
             });
         });
     </script>
     ');

}

add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'load_custom_logo_js' );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Uncaught TypeError: Property '$' of object [object Object] is not a function
```

Are you positive you're accessing the jQuery object correctly? You should look into how [WordPress uses noConflict mode](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script#jQuery_noConflict_Wrappers).

> In the noConflict() mode, the global $ shortcut for jQuery is not available, but you can still use:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery(#somefunction) ...
});
```

**As a footnote**, as a developer, whether it's for themes or plugins, you should make use of development tools that are at your disposal. Your browser likely has a Developer Tool or Console that will show you anything that's wrong with your code. [WordPress Debugging](http://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress) will also flag any errors that might still work, but are technically incorrect code.